# putting float numbers in lists

Tags: python, python-3.x

my program reads a text file as every line as lists.then it puts all the elements with the same index number in a lists.so basically it puts all the columns in lists.and then turns the elements into float numbers.and after that i have several lines in my program that look like this

```
p1 = float(p[2])*dollar/maximum[money[0]]
p2 = ...
```

and so on. when i write

```
print(p1)
```

it gives me

```
1.0
2.0
3.0
```

and when i write print(p2) it gives me

```
5.0
6.0
7.0
```

i want to save these numbers (in lists) in such a way that the they look like this

```
[1.0, 5.0]
[2.0, 6.0]
[3.0, 7.0]
```

how do i do that?

Comment: What data-type is `p1`?  I would have guessed `float`, but apparently not with how it prints ...

Comment: What is `p2`, there's no pattern here, you don't give us the input arrays, just the processing.

Comment: Whatever the solution, I bet it involves `zip` :)

Comment: p1 is float. i just wrote those numbers as examples.i'll update them now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just create lists:

```
somelist = [p1, p2]
```

You probably want to append those to another data structure initialized outside of your loop:

```
somelargerlist = []

for presumed_loop_variable in presumed_loop_not_shown:
    p1 = ...
    p2 = ...
    somelist = [p1, p2]
    somelargerlist.append(somelist)
```

Comment: that will give him [[1,2,3], [5,6,7]]

Comment: @IonutHulub: no, it won't, not with what I understand from the OP code (that wasn't shared).

Comment: @IonutHulub -- I think Martijn is assuming it is done in a loop ... This boils down to the question "What exactly are p1 and p2?".  Ionut seems to assume they are lists whereas Martijn is assuming constants.

Comment: There's not enough information here to form any sort of answer.

Comment: @Serdalis second that...

Comment: @Serdalis: It's called Psychic debugging. Making an educated guess as to what is happening. If the OP is calling `print(p1)` and `print(p2)` there is a loop to form the output shown.

Comment: Bad question, this answer should not be down voted though

Comment: @Martijn Pieters that won't work anyway because somelist will only store the last couple of items. in this case: [3,7]

Comment: @IonutHulub: read on: *You probably want to append those to another data structure outside of your loop*. I've made it more explicit.

Comment: +1 for the psychic pseudo-code.

Comment: i tried putting them in lists but it gives me the error:
'float' object is not iterable

Comment: @shaghayeghtavakoli: Then you made an error in how you added them to a list; sounds like you tried to loop over the float value suggesting you *replaced* the list with a float instead of adding it to the list.

Comment: your answer kind of worked but it's supposed to give me 38 lists and instead,it gives me 10 lists.i'm trying to find the problem

Comment: @shaghayeghtavakoli: your question is *way* too light on details to be able to help you with that.

Comment: the problem is that now it only gives me [1.0, 5.0] several times and not the other numbers